# Lenovo Thinkpad 25 (retro) webcam doesn't work with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, webcam

The camera on my thinkpad just displays a very static-y image. I could post screenshots if that would help. Reaching out to Lenovo, it seems that particular Thinkpad doesn't support Ubuntu officially. My question is, does it work for ANYONE with this Thinkpad model, in which case I should get the hardware inspected, or is it really not supported?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out that TP25 has two integrated cameras, the other one is IR camera sending the garbled image, and the other one is the normal camera. The IR camera appears to be the default camera, and some applications allow you to switch between cameras, others don't.

I ended up disabling the IR camera completely, as I don't need it, and now I get the pretty picture from the normal camera by default.
My solution is here: [How do I change the default webcam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119743/how-do-i-change-the-default-webcam/1119832#1119832)